# Difference between Pickerview and Tableview in iOS

Tags: uitableview, uipickerview

I am new to iOS Developement, Can any one say what is the major difference between this two views, Table view and Picker View..

Answer (score 1):

A table view is much more versatile than a picker. It is the main mechanism to display list data on mobile devices. The most important difference is that you can subclass the main unit, `UITableViewCell` to create rich and individual interfaces. Conceptionally, tableviews can be basically infinite in content length.

A picker view is much more limited both in size, styling and features. It is really meant as a standardized way to choose from a limited amount mainly strings.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that there is requirement of compare UITableViewController and Pickerview controller. We can customize UITabelview as per requirement by using custom cell but not in picker view.

Picker view is just to choose one from the list. We can use table view in place of picker as per need but not picker in place of table view. If we take technically there is not much difference between in delegate methods calling on events. But On interface builder and as per utilization of view components table view have more supervision.